# What is my maths score as a percentage?

Tags: percentages

In my maths module, there are 2 phases. In the 1st phase, there are 2 tests. In the 2nd phase there is 1 test. 
Phase 1's total weight is 60% and phase 2's total weight is 40%.

This is what I scored: 
In Phase 1 - test 1: 92% 
In Phase 1 - test 2: 66% 
In Phase 2 - test 1: 88%

So I want to know my overall percentage of this maths module. 
I'm not sure how much each individual test in phase 1 is weighted.. but I think i remember that Phase 1 test 1 is 20% out of the 60%...

Comment: There exist numerous online grade calculators: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=grade+calculator

Comment: To do it by hand, take the weighted average of the tests.  In your example (and assuming that phase1-test1 was 20% of phase1 and phase1-test2 was 80% of phase1) you have: $.6(.2\cdot 92 + .8\cdot 66)+.4(88) = 77.92$

Comment: What material was the module on?

Answer (score 0):

$12\cdot\frac{92}{100}+48\cdot\frac{66}{100}+40\cdot\frac{88}{100}=11.04+31.68+35.2=77.92$

Because if Test 1 of Phase 1 weighs its 20%, then it weighs $\frac{20}{100}\cdot60$ of the total, similarly test 2 - Phase 1 weighs 48% of total.